# Changing Datasource to SQL Server in TABLEAU

Tags: tableau-api

We are changing our Datasource from MS Access to SQL Server. Question,
Will we need to **redevelop** the Worksheets and Dashboards
Is there a way to have a Worksheet to connect to the new Datasource?
The tables are same between MS Access the SQL Server.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to redevelop all the worksheets and dashboards, just change the datasource you use in tableau. Create your new data source, which hopefully has very similar field names and data types as your original data source. Then go to the Data menu and choose Replace Data Source). Tableau will change your existing worksheets to reference the new data source.

Once the previous is done go to any of your worksheets and fix any problems, usually you’ll see a few fields that were different for some reason. You can replace the references to the fields if necessary. (right click on any field dimensions or measure, replace references) And might need to do some other minor surgery, delete old fields repair a group or something.

It should be all good. When you’re sure you are done with the old data source, you can close it from the data menu.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that Alex.